# Error creating bean with name 'jsonView' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, json-view

I don't understand why this problem caused.

Anyone who knows this problem?

I tried to change prefix folder(WEB-INF/jsp) and to insert jackson dependency code in pom.xml

bottom of this text is Error log

**Error log**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jsonView' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/action-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4998)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
            ... 29 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.<init>(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:59)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
            ... 31 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1172)
            ... 37 more

        1월 23, 2019 1:09:50 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
        SEVERE: Servlet [action] in web application [/start] threw load() exception
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1172)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.<init>(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:59)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4998)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5312)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1413)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.pineapple</groupId>
<artifactId>start</artifactId>
<name>basicSpring</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.2</jackson.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is `action-servlet.xml` code. and I check jackson-databind which is version `2.9.2`

I set prefix and suffix that way. and is this correct?

thx feedback : )

**action-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="start"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean id="LoggerInterceptor" class="start.common.logger.LoggerInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0" />
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />   

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" p:order="1"
    p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp">
</bean>
</beans>
```

In this code, Error Part is this point.

```
<bean id="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />`
```

Comment: What version of jackson-databind are you using? Do you see the `ObjectMapper` class in that JAR file?

Comment: Also, please include the relevant parts of the `action-servlet.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Instead `MappingJacksonJsonView` try `MappingJackson2JsonView`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
 <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thx for this problem, but ecplise could not find class `MappingJackson2JsonView`

Comment: Do this cmd in your terminal, mvn clean package